# problem in displaying a question with concat, foreach and explode in php

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, concatenation, strpos

I have a table in mysql. The name of this table is `questiontbl`. The questions are stored in this table. A question is displayed randomly to the user. This question should not be repeated. So the user ID is stored in a column called `uid`. I have some problems:

First, the question is displayed multiple times instead of once.

Second, the `uid` field update does not work correctly. For example, if the user ID is 40 and must be added to the field once, it will be added three times.

Please review my code and help me solve its problems.

my table:

| id | questiontitle | uid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | questionA | 19,40,15,17, |
| 6 | questionB | 19, |

Note: The user ID should not be stored repeatedly in the `uid` column.

My code:

```
<?php
$uid2=$_SESSION['id'];
$get1 = "SELECT * FROM questiontbl ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$get2=mysqli_query($conn,$get1);
$get3=mysqli_fetch_assoc($get2);
$questionid=$get3['id'];
$now=$get3['uid'];
$now2=explode(',',$now);
foreach ($now2 as $data) 
{
    if (strpos($data,$uid2) !== FALSE )
    {
        header("Location: startnew.php");
    }
    else
    {                               
        $final_show=$get3['questiontitle'];
        echo $final_show;                               
        $update_idq = "UPDATE questiontbl SET uid=concat(uid,'$uid2,') WHERE id='$questionid' LIMIT1";
        mysqli_query($conn, $update_idq);
    }           
}
?>
```

Comment: You should read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: It might be interesting to see if you can use `find_in_set()` to limit the select to only find questions that this user hasn't already answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting repetition because you are iterating over all the values in the `uid` column to see if you have a match with the session `id` value, and each time the values don't match you are updating your table. Instead, after `explode`ing the value, use [`in_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array) to see if the session `id` value exists in the `uid` column:

```php
$uid2=$_SESSION['id'];
$get1 = "SELECT * FROM questiontbl ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$get2=mysqli_query($conn,$get1);
$get3=mysqli_fetch_assoc($get2);
$questionid=$get3['id'];
$now=$get3['uid'];
$now2=explode(',',$now);
if (in_array($uid2, $now2)) {
    header("Location: startnew.php");
}
else {                               
    $final_show=$get3['questiontitle'];
    echo $final_show;                               
    $update_idq = "UPDATE questiontbl SET uid=concat(uid,",$uid2") WHERE id='$questionid' LIMIT 1";
    mysqli_query($conn, $update_idq);
}
```

Note also that variable substitution only occurs in double quoted strings (and you need the comma before the `id` value) so you need to change

```
SET uid=concat(uid,'$uid2,')
```

to

```
SET uid=concat(uid,",$uid2")
```

Finally you have a typo, `LIMIT1` should be `LIMIT 1` although it ought to be unnecessary for that query.